# Почему не запускается приложение

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, spring-security

Делала приложение по примеру. На видео код рабочий, а у меня не запускается.

```
 Connected to server
[2017-11-30 03:42:41,277] Artifact SpringSecurity:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
30-Nov-2017 15:42:45.294 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
30-Nov-2017 15:42:47.636 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
30-Nov-2017 15:42:47.794 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
30-Nov-2017 15:42:47.797 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
30-Nov-2017 15:42:47.800 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
30-Nov-2017 15:42:48.182 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
30-Nov-2017 15:42:48.609 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
30-Nov-2017 15:42:48.891 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.<init> HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
30-Nov-2017 15:42:48.997 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit> HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.1.Final
30-Nov-2017 15:42:50.237 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Nov-2017 15:42:50.238 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
30-Nov-2017 15:42:50.257 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2017-11-30 03:42:50,271] Artifact SpringSecurity:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
30-Nov-2017 15:42:50.761 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Oksana\Desktop\Oksana\Setup\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager]
30-Nov-2017 15:42:50.869 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Oksana\Desktop\Oksana\Setup\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager] has finished in [108] ms
```

[Ссылка на исходник](https://github.com/OksanaShumei/SpringSecurityWebApp)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть в том числе и потому, что возможно над классом UserDetailsServiceImpl.java должна стоять аннототация @Service

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло

Comment: Если после выяснения причины вы уберёте @Service из UserDetailsServiceImpl.java и  ваше приложение не будет работать, поставьте "Ответ был полезен" моему ответу, пожалуйста.